# Order taxonomy terms wordpress

Tags: custom-taxonomy, taxonomy, terms, order

It seems like something really simple, however I can't find a good solution to what I am looking for.
I created a page template that shows all my taxonomy term of a taxonomy called "**news**" eg:
paper1, paper2 etc etc

this is the code I generated:

```
<?php
$post_type = 'article';
$tax = 'news';
$tax_terms = get_terms( $tax );
if ($tax_terms) {
    foreach ($tax_terms  as $tax_term) {
    $args = array(
        'post_type' => $post_type,
        "$tax" => $tax_term->slug,
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
        'order' => 'ASC',
        'caller_get_posts'=> 1
    );

        $my_query = null;
        $my_query = new WP_Query($args);

        if( $my_query->have_posts() ) : ?>

//here comes my styling for any term including it's custom post types

<?php else : ?>
        <?php endif; // if have_posts()
        wp_reset_query();

    } // end foreach #tax_terms
}
?>
```

everything works fine and the page generate all the taxonomy terms and their posts one by one like so (just a demonstration of course..):

```
paper1
 - article 1
 - article 1
 - article 1
 - article 1

paper2
 - article 1
 - article 1
 - article 1
 - article 1

paper3
 - article 1
 - article 1
 - article 1
 - article 1
```

The problem is that it displays everything in an a Descending order and I want to change it to Ascending. I always need to latest "paper" to show on top.
Notice that I did add:

```
'order' => 'ASC',
```

to my arguments but it doesn't work on custom taxonomy terms and it keeps showing all the terms (papers) in a Descending order. I thought it should work like regular categories but surprisingly it doesn't.

can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not setting an order anywhere for [`get_terms`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_terms), you're setting it for the query of articles *within each term*. You need to pass arguments to `get_terms` if you want an order other than default, which is `ASC`.

```
$tax = 'news';
$tax_args = array(
    'order' => 'DESC'
);
$tax_terms = get_terms( $tax, $tax_args );
```